# Bluetooth toggle not working in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 21.04

I updated my OS yesterday from 20.10 to 21.04. Everything was fine today until I tried to connect my Bluetooth earphones to my PC.

The Bluetooth service remains turned off even when I turn the toggle switch on.

Subsequently, it does not even scan for devices because, as expected, it is not switched on for the OS.

Is the issue common after this upgrade?

Please let me know if someone has a solution.

As you can see, Bluetooth is off, and it is not showing an option to switch it on.

[image]

And now even though I have switched it on, it is showing that it is off.

[image]

The issue is not only what the system shows.

It does not scan for devices.

Here:

[image]

[image]

In the second screenshot, I have switched on the toggle but it still does not scan for Bluetooth devices.

**UPDATE AS OF 4th May, 2021:**

1. I had reported the bug to Ubuntu. They have merged my report with an already existing bug report. If anyone wishes to follow it, here's the link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926062
2. Someone on the launchpad site had pointed out in the comments that using the command `systemctl restart bluetooth` will turn on the Bluetooth from the terminal even if the toggle is not working. I believe this solution is working until Cannonical provides some fix updates.

Comment: Please file a proper bug report for this issue.

Comment: What does `rfkill list bluetooth` tell you? Does `rfkill unblock bluetooth` fix the problem? If it does, I have a bash script that toggles Bluetooth on and off which I can make available. –

Comment: I have not tried this command. I had reported this bug on Launchpad where another guy who had the same issue told a workaround in the comments. ``` systemctl restart bluetooth``` this command turns on the Bluetooth if it is not already on. I guess we'll have to wait till someone repairs the bluez package for a proper solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

> substitute "quiet splash" by "quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
> save changes (nano only): CTRL+x / key y / Enter

sudo update-grub

> restart computer.

Comment: I Have the same issue and this solution is not related and not worked.

Comment: have you checked Settings/Power tab? It must show two items: Wifi and Bluetooth. In same systems this solution works, because Bluetooth appears in Power tab of Settings. Also try turn power on / off for Bluetooth, or in Ubuntu menu upper-right also turn on / off.

Comment: This bug is not related to the power panel, it's about the Bluetooth panel that does not work properly when switching on/off. I test your proposed solution and it did not work.

Comment: but is it Bluetooth option also present in Power tab? If yes, maybe work reboot and enter BIOS menu (F2/DEL/etc.) and turn it on there...

Comment: For me this suggestion worked fine

Answer (score 1):

i had the very same problem on my Toshiba Satellite and it seems like Wayland is causing this just logout and choose Xorg login turn the airplane mode off and that's it Bluetooth an Wifi will work normal again after that you can logoff and chose Wayland if you prefer to I hope this will help you